# MATLAB: Using ODE solvers?

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-integration

This is a really basic question but this is the first time I've used MATLAB and I'm stuck.
I need to simulate a simple series RC network using 3 different numerical integration techniques. I think I understand how to use the ode solvers, but I have no idea how to enter the differential equation of the system. Do I need to do it via an m-file?

It's just a simple RC circuit in the form:

```
RC dy(t)/dt + y(t) = u(t)
```

with zero initial conditions. I have the values for R, C the step length and the simulation time but I don't know how to use MATLAB particularly well.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need a function file that takes *t* and *y* as input and gives *dy* as output.  It would be its own file with the following header.

```
function dy = rigid(t,y)
```

Save it as rigid.m on the MATLAB path.

From there you would put in your differential equation.  You now have a function.  Here is a simple one:

```
function dy = rigid(t,y)

dy = sin(t);
```

From the command line or a script, you need to drive this function through ODE45

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@rigid,[0 2*pi],[0]);
```

This will give you your function (rigid.m) running from **time 0** through **time 2*pi** with an **initial y of zero**.

Plot this:

```
plot(T,Y)
```

[image]

More of the MATLAB documentation is here:

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ode23tb.html